# react webpack scss closures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack

I may has mis-interpenetrated the tutorials, but I thought you could include `sccs` files inside of a single react module using webpack and have only the `css` from the `scss` apply to that view.

So when I navigate to a page that doesn't include the `<Index />` then the `Index.scss` would not be rendered inside of the pages `<head>`

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import '../../scss/pages/Index.scss' 
//^^ This is the individual styles that I would like to be shown on the <Index />

export default React.createClass({

    render(){
        return (
            <NavLink to="/Home">
                <Logo />
            </NavLink>
        );
    }

});
```

However Index.scss is being appiled globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library that allows you to do that it's called CSS Modules.

It works like this

```
import styles from  '../../scss/pages/Index.scss' 

export default React.createClass({

    render(){
        return (
            <header className={styles.header}>
            </header>
        );
    }

});
```

In order to use CSS modules you have to active it in your webpack configuration

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css?modules!sass'
    }]
}
```

If you want to read about it,[css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader)

Comment: Are you able to target an entire page with it? Rather than just elements?

Comment: Do you mean without using classNames={styles.**} ? No, when you use CSS Modules, your CSS names are not the same anymore, every style is changed to an unique name  in order to make them "local".

Comment: Argh ok, then that changes the way I need to do everything :) But thank you